# Python 'for item in list' not changing list items

Tags: python, for-loop, foreach

```
board = ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']
for item in board:
    if item == 'b':
        item = 'a'
print(board)
```

The result of this block of code is that none of the list items turn to 'a'. I cant seem to figure out why that is. I can still do a for loop where I use an index value to change each item in the list like such.

```
board = ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']
for i in range(0, len(board)):
    if board[i] == 'b':
        board[i] = 'a'
print(board)
```

I don't understand why the first solution dosent work

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: In the first code snippet all it accomplishes is to reassign the `item` variable to `'a'`. In the second the assignment directly overwrites a particular element of `board`.

Comment: `board[:] = ['a' if item == 'b' else item for item in board]`

Comment: "I cant seem to figure out why that is." This is simple - because nowhere in your code do you mutate the list `board`. You simply assign some object to the variable `item`. That does not mutate your list. `board[i] = "a"`, on the otherhand, is using a list mutator method

Comment: `item` has no direct connection to `board`, either inside or outside of the loop.  On each new iteration of the loop, the next element from `board` is assigned to `item`.  Any explicit assignments to `item` have no effect on `board` either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`item` is a variable. `for item in board:` keeps assigning values from `board` to `item` as the loop progresses. `item` holds a reference to a value in `board` but it has no idea that `board` exists or holds the value too. You could track the position in `board` with `enumerate` and assign as needed

```
board = ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']
for i, item in enumerate(board):
    if item == 'b':
        board[i] = 'a'
print(board)
```

Or you could use a list comprehension to create a new board

```
board = ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']
newboard = [value if value != 'b' else 'a' for value in board]
```

Or assign that new list back to the original `board` variable

```
board = ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']
board = [value if value != 'b' else 'a' for value in board]
```

Or refill the original list with the new values

```
board = ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']
board[:] = [value if value != 'b' else 'a' for value in board]
```

Comment: There's no need to create the throw-away list in the last version.  You can just assign directly with the generator, i.e. `board[:] = (v if v != 'b' else 'a' for v in board)`.  That way you avoid the unnecessary creation of a temporary list.  I.e. just replace the `[]` with `()`.

Comment: @TomKarzes - The list's slice assignment function will create its own temporary list from the generator. Your example is good and should be in the list of how to do things, but won't make any significant difference.

Comment: I guess that makes sense.  It can't do the slice assignment until it knows how big the slice it.

Answer (score 0):

You need a small change in your code. You need to access the items in your list in sequence and see if, at a particular location, there exists the letter 'b'.

```
board = ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']
for item in range(len(board)):
    if board[item] == 'b':
        board[item] = 'a'
print(board)
```

Hopefully, this helps.